# Insert two graphs on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, morris.js

It's possibile insert two graphs on the same page?
I extract data from DB and then draw the graph on the page. 
This is my pseudo-code that use for draw the graphs, I change the id element but I show only the first graph, while the second doesn't work.

```
<? $res_app = mysql_query("SELECT ... ") 
...
?>
<div id="graph"></div>
<pre id="code" class="prettyprint linenums">
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'graph',
  data: [
    {value: 70, label: 'foo'},
    {value: 15, label: 'bar'},
    {value: 10, label: 'baz'},
    {value: 5, label: 'A really really long label'}
  ],
  formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
});
</pre>

<? $res_app = mysql_query("SELECT ... ") 
...
?>
<div id="graph1"></div>
<pre id="code" class="prettyprint linenums">
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'graph1',
    data: [
      {value: 50, label: 'foo', formatted: 'at least 50%' },
      {value: 25, label: 'bar', formatted: 'approx. 25%' },
      {value: 20, label: 'baz', formatted: 'approx. 20%' },
      {value: 5, label: 'A really really long label', formatted: 'at most 5%' }
    ],
   formatter: function (x, data) { return data.formatted; }
});
</pre>
```

Comment: You might not find many people here familiar with morris.js – it's quite a small library. You are probably best off emailing the author if nothing shows up here.

Comment: May problem be in ````<pre id="code">```` occurs two times?

Comment: I send an email to author of library. The solution is very simple, it's necessary move the code into <script> block e remove the <pre> blocks. The fact that there's two <pre> blocks with the same ID in the code has caused only one block to be executed. (@nord_ua solution). Now it's works.

Comment: @reb2awrl : Can you place your comment as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution in order to render multiple charts on one page:

```
var $lineChart = $('.line-chart-js');
if($lineChart.length) {
    $lineChart.each(function (index, element) {
        var chartData = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-chart'));
        new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: $(this),
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: chartData,
            // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
            xkey: $(this).attr('data-x'),
            // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
            ykeys: [$(this).attr('data-y')],
            // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
            // chart.
            labels: [$(this).attr('data-label')]
        });
    });
}
```

HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="line-chart-js" data-x='xkey' data-y='ykey' data-label='label' data-chart='<?php echo json_encode($yourArray); ?>'></div>
```

This way you can reuse your class and won't have to write seperate javascript for each of your graphs.